# Get ID of a log-in in WMIC

Tags: windows, authentication, wmic

I'm aware that users who log-in in a computer has SID which may be used as an ID for the user. I wanna know if a **log-in event** in the computer has also a corresponding ID/token regardless of the user.

For example:
User A logs in - gets an ID of the LOG-IN event
User A logs out

User A logs in again - gets a different ID of the log-in event

I'll be very glad if it's through wmic

Comment: User's `SID` is the same, changeless: try `wmic useraccount get /value` or `whoami /user`. On the contrary, `Logon ID` changes for a particular user from session to session (you could see it in Windows security log, e.g. `EventID=4634` _Logoff_ and corresponding `EventID=4624` _Logon_). And yes, you could elicit it via `WMI`; not easy but feasible solution...

Comment: Logon ID it is! thanks @JosefZ

Comment: Truly: I'm a bit confused comparing `Logon ID` in the _Windows security log_ (a _number_ in hexadecimal) with `whoami /logonid` output (something very, very similar to a `SID`-like string). Amazing Microsoft:)